# Concurrent Method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that has one method that serves the most work. I want to make multiple calls to this method, running it concurrently (to have multiple searches simultaneously). The method I want to call uses my class's local attributes so I can't simply create a new class with this method in it as it won't be able to access my other class' attributes as they have different memory space.

Example:

```
class mainWork { 
    static int localInt;
    static String testString;

    public static void main(){
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                doWork();
            }
        }.run();
    }

    public void doWork(){
        localInt = 1;
        testString = "Hi";
    }
}
```

Creating an anonymous Runnable inner class does not work as that thread can't access mainWorks attributes. If I create a separate class, extend Thread I have the same problem. Is there a way (maybe not using threads at all) I can call a method that will still have access to the attributes from the class that is calling it while running simultaneous calls? I want to call doWork many times at once to speed up an operation. Tasks maybe?

Comment: "Creating an anonymous Runnable inner class does not work as that thread can't access `mainWork`s attributes." Then perhaps the attributes should not be in `mainWork`

Comment: Also in your example you are creating a runn**able** but not actually running it.

Comment: I'll change it, so it it started. @Michael I need the attributes in the calling class.

Comment: @Michael I should have tested. It's just I'm in the middle of a project that I can't post source to public on this.

Comment: You don't have to. Just create a new project which demonstrates your problem that you *can* post online. Like you have done but, y'know, actually run it first ;)

Comment: Ok Michael advice taken. Thanks

Comment: No problem. So what you've got will technically execute but only on a single thread. If you want it to execute concurrently, you need to pass the Runnable to a new thread and then start that.

Comment: Yes it will execute but I need the separate execution to access the attributes

Comment: It does. There are only 2 variables in that program. Any additional threads will only be accessing the same 2 values. You *are* open to race conditions though.

Comment: You seem to be messing up the use of *static* and non-static elements. Go ahead and figure out which elements should be static (`main()`?) and which don't (`localInt`,...?). Then check if/when/where you need to create an *instance* of your class (`mainWork mw = new mainWork()`) on which you can call the non-static method(s) (`doWork()`). - Or, for now, just make the `doWork` method static like `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many problems in your code :

- Wrong main method declaration
- To call a method you have to use `()` -> `doWork();`
- You have to use `;` in the end of your statement `new Runnable() {...};`
- You can't assign a String to a int `testString = "Hi";`

---

Your code should look like :

```
int localInt;
String testString;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MainWork a = new MainWork(); 
            a.doWork();
        }
    };

}

public void doWork() {
    localInt = 1;
    testString = "Hi";
}
```

---

Until now your program will compiled, but do nothing, to start your thread you have to use :

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainWork a = new MainWork(); 
        a.doWork();
    }
};

new Thread(r).start();
```

---

Another point, don't use lower letter in first name of your class mainWork instead you have to use MainWork

Comment: "Your attributes should be static also your method" hm, not necessarily. `run()` could be implemented e.g. `new MainWork().doWork()` or a number of other ways. Static isn't the only to solve this.

Comment: @Michael yes check my answer now, i think the runnable  should do something

Comment: The Runnable will run but the attributes from the calling class will not be affected. I need separate execution that still has access to calling class attributes.

Comment: @Michael you can't call a method in main method if it is not static, else you have to use `ClassName a = new ClassName();
a.doWork();`

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said? (minus the redundant assignment)

Comment: Re, "You have to use ; in the end of your statement..."  The original version created a `Runnable` object and then called its `run()` method.  Admittedly, that was a very roundabout way of calling `doWork()`; but your "fixed" version creates a `Runnable` and then does nothing with it at all.  Doesn't even save a reference to it in a variable.  That seems like a step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your question, I made this short example for deal with parallel processing without concerning about threads, this is a "non blocking code" that can be easier to implement.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

/**
 *JAVA 8 introduces a new concept for dealing with concurrencies  
 *CompletableFuture
 */

class MainWork {
    static int localInt;
    static String testString;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(MainWork::doWork).thenAccept(System.out::println);
        System.in.read(); //this line is only to keep the program running
    }

    public static List<String> doWork() {
        localInt = 100;
        testString = "Hi";

        List<String> greetings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int x = 0; x < localInt; x++) {

            greetings.add(testString);
        }
        return greetings;
    }
}
```